# reading information from an array of objects filled with arrays of different data types

Tags: java, arrays

I've created an array of objects, with 5 different arrays primarily containing integers and strings (names of people and vehicle types). My question is once I've created an object array, how do I display the information pertaining to a selected index?

```
class Vehicle
{
    int passengers, fuelCapacity, mpg;
    String type, name;

    Vehicle(String n, String t, int p, int f, int m)
    {
        passengers = p;
        fuelCapacity = f;
        mpg = m;
        type = t;
        name = n;
    }

    int range()
    {
        return mpg * fuelCapacity;
    }

}

// Declaring Vehicles array for the pertinent information.
Vehicle[] iVehicles = new Vehicle[10];

// array consisting of the types of vehicles.
String[] types = {"Truck", "Sportscar", "SUV", "Sedan", "Coupe", "Truck","Truck", "Sportscar", "SUV", "Sedan"};

// array consisting of the number of passengers per vehicle.
int[] nmbrOfPassengers = {2,2,8,4,4,4,2,2,7,4};

// array consisting of each vehicles fuel capacity in gallons.
int[] fuelCapacity = {15,15,20,20,12,15,19,19,16,10};

//array consisting of integers containing each vehicles miles per gallon.
int[] milesPerGallon = {20,18,13,35,31,34,39,19,22,25};


// array consisting of the names
String[] aNames = { "brian","bob","fred","janet","claire","bill","rudy","sandy","samuel","joan"};

for (int i = 0; i < iVehicles.length; i++)
{
    iVehicles[i] = new Vehicle(aNames[i], types[i], nmbrOfPassengers[i], fuelCapacity[i], milesPerGallon[i]);
}

// This is the portion i'm stumped on.
System.out.print(iVehicles[1]);
```

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Please post your Vehicle class and the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print like this:

```
System.out.print(iVehicles[1].passengers);
System.out.print(iVehicles[1].fuelCapacity);
System.out.print(iVehicles[1].mpg);
System.out.print(iVehicles[1].type);
System.out.print(iVehicles[1].name);
```

**Or**

in your `class Vehicle` override the `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() { 
    return ("Passengers: " + this.passengers); // Concatenate all other fields.
}
```

Now `System.out.println(iVehicles[1])` will print what the `toString()` returns.

Comment: @A.Vic you can accept the answer if it helped you by clicking the big check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display the information pertaining to a selected index the code is:

```
System.out.println(iVehicles[index])
```

However, `System.out.println` will automatically call `toString` method of class Vehicle. Unless you have override it, the default implementation (inherited from Object class) is useless for an user.
So, in order to display the information you should provide a custom implementation of this method, in which you concatenate in a String, the values from the Vehicle attributes that you want to display.